# Changing Activities in Java (Android Studio) without extending Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Hey guys I'm relatively new to Java and I am making a game in Android Studio. The issue I have is that I am trying to switch levels when a user reaches a certain score. The Game class itself extends the SurfaceView class while the menu itself extends Activity.

My main Menu class extends Activity and I have programmed it to run the game when the button (Play Game) is being clicked by the user, however, I have tried copying and pasting the code and it doesn't seem to work within the Game class.

```
class SnakeEngine extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    public void update() {
     if (score == 5){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, level2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    }
```

Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Try using  `Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), level2.class);` and
       `getContext().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: I tried it and I get the error "Cannot resolve method 'startActivity'"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SurfaceView` extends from `View` class which has a method `getContext()` so you can use it like

```
class SnakeEngine extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    public void update() {
     if (score == 5){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, level2.class);
        getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```